# How can I save a DropDown into a Database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I've looked really hard on this but I can't get my head around AJAX working with PHP.

This is what I have and when a user clicks on the dropdown I would like it to save into my database

```
<select>
  <?php $taskStatus = "SELECT * FROM task_status WHERE used = 1 ORDER BY id ASC ";
   $taskresults = $conn->query($taskStatus) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   while($taskStatusRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($taskresults)) {
     echo " <option  value= ". $taskStatusRow['name'] ." >". $taskStatusRow['name'] ." </option>";
   }
  ?>
</select>
```

And this is the query i'd like to run:

```
INSERT INTO snagging (taskstatus, updated_at) 
WHERE ID = 1234 
VALUES taskStatusRow['name'], $now);
```

Comment: Well, AJAX involves JavaScript so... where's your JavaScript code?

Comment: I have no idea what to do with JS..so

Comment: Then it looks like its back to the books and tutorials. Its really not rocket science

Comment: there are hundreds of ajax examples online already, possibly even for this exact use case. You can try one and adapt to your needs. No need for the wheel to be re-invented here. If you try something and get stuck then please post your attempt here and any errors you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you a overall flow of AJAX here. I tried to provide comments so as to show the control flow.

```
<select id="selectOption">  //******* Assign an ID
    <?php $taskStatus = "SELECT * FROM task_status WHERE used = 1 ORDER BY id ASC ";
    $taskresults = $conn->query($taskStatus) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($taskStatusRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($taskresults)) {

        echo " <option  value= ". $taskStatusRow['name'] ." >". $taskStatusRow['name'] ." </option>";

    }
    ?>
</select>
```

jQuery + AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectOption").change(function(){ //** on selecting an option based on ID you assigned
        var optionVal = $("#selectOption option:selected").val(); //** get the selected option's value

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //**how data is send
            url: "MYPROCESSPAGE.php", //** where to send the option data so that it can be saved in DB
            data: {optionVal: optionVal }, //** send the selected option's value to above page
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                //** what should do after value is saved to DB and returned from above URL page.
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Inside your `MYPROCESSPAGE.php`, you can access the data passed via AJAX like:

```
<?php

$selectedOptionVal = $_POST['optionVal'];

//DB CONNECTION STEPS
.
.
.
// You are trying to "UPDATE" a table data based on some ID and not inserting. Included both operations

// If you are INSERTING A new table entry, use below code.
//INSERT INTO snagging (taskstatus, updated_at) VALUES ('$selectedOptionVal', 'Now()');

// If you are UPDATING an existing table entry, use below code.
//UPDATE snagging SET taskstatus = '$selectedOptionVal', updated_at = 'Now()' WHERE ID = 1234;

?>
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @Gem It's because you can't use `$_POST['price']` in ajax.php, since you are not passing any `<input type="" name="price">` field. You can't access price inside the div by naming it as `price'.

Comment: You could pass price as an hidden field as `<input type="hidden" name="price">` and change the following:

`<b><div id="result" name="price"></div></b>` to `<b><div id="result"></div></b><input type="hidden" name="price" id="price">`

and change this in drop down onchange success

`$('#result').html(data);` to `$('#result').html(data);$('#price').val(data);`

Comment: Instead of `echo "2500";`, set the cost in a `$price` variable and shipping charge in `$shipping_charge` and echo those two variables wherever necessary.